# ordinary differential linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A \in Mat_{n \times n} ( \mathbb{R} )$, and $0 \neq v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly independent. Given that $x(t) = e^{-t}v +te^{-t}w$ is a solution for the ODE $\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)$, find another solution that is independent of $x$.

I suspect $we^{-t}$ to be the other solution (I hope I'm right), and I suppose that the way to show is is by that $(A+I)we^{-t}=0$ hence $\dot{we^{-t}}=Awe^{-t}$. But I don't know how to start.

Comment: Maybe I'm slow thinking now, but what exactly is meant by "find another solution that is independent of $v$, $w$"?

Comment: No, you are ok... It was all me - sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function $x(t)=e^{-t}v+te^{-t}w$ satisfies
$$
                   \frac{dx}{dt}=Ax
$$
And
$$
              \frac{dx}{dt} = -e^{-t}v-te^{-t}w+e^{-t}w = -x+e^{-t}w \\
                        \frac{dx}{dt}+x=e^{-t}w \\
                           (A+I)x=e^{-t}w.
$$
Therefore, $y=e^{-t}w$ is a solution of $\frac{dy}{dt}=Ay$ because
$$
             \frac{d}{dt}\{(A+I)x\}= (A+I)\frac{dx}{dt}=(A+I)Ax=A\{(A+I)x\}.
$$
It's not hard to check that $y$ and $x$ are linearly independent solutions.

Comment: In the 4'th line - isn't it suppose to be: $\dot{x} = -e^{-t}v-te^{-t}w+e^{-t}w$ ?

Comment: @UriaMor : Yes. I fixed that now.